# Want to apend Ajax response data in select option

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Want to Append Select option but don't know how to fetch response values in select option.

All values fetched in response but cant append in select option, the syntax I think wrong

```js
success: function (response) {

   if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#state").empty();
        $("#state").append('<option value="" selected disabled>Select State</option>');
        $.each(response, function (id, name) {
              $("#state").append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + ' </option>');

        });
    }
}
```

**Console Output:** The Value fetched but cant apend in select option

```
[{…}]
  0: {id: 4, name: "Valencia"}
  1: {id: 5, name: "ABC"}
     length: 2
     __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you add your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each` applied to an object returns according to manual:

```
jQuery.each( object, callback )
```

where:

```
object
Type: Object
The object to iterate over.

callback
Type: Function( String propertyName, Object valueOfProperty )
The function that will be executed on every value.
```

So inside `name` you have an object.
According to this to fetch the `name` property you have to use `name.name`.

So, using better variable's name you can have:

```
$.each(response, function (id, element) {
          $("#state").append('<option value="' + element.id + '">' + element.name + ' </option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (response) {

   if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#state").empty();
        $("#state").append('<option value="" selected disabled>Select State</option>');
        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
              $("#state").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + response[index].name + ' </option>');

        });
    }
```

The each function is implemented incorrectly, see the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

The first parameter is the index, and is optional, the second is the the current object in the loop.

I changed you code to show how to use each one

edit: missed a "."

Comment: your code doesn't work.. you have to use `response[index].name`. Why don't use `value.name` instead?

Comment: @Wolfetto youre correct thanks, missed the dot there. I Would also use the value.name instead, however I just illustrated how the index can be used as na example

Answer (score 0):

you have not extracting values index wise. you have an array of two json objects.
so you are required to extract using index like below.

```
success: function (response) {

   if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#state").empty();
        $("#state").append('<option value="" selected disabled>Select           State</option>');
        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
              $("#state").append('<option value="' + response[index].id + '">' + response[index].name + ' </option>');

        });
    }
```